# Is there an equivalent of C#'s verbatim string literals in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I know I can create a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) in C# by using the @ symbol. For example, the usual

```
String path = "C:\\MyDocs\\myText.txt";
```

can also be re-written as

```
String path = @"C:\MyDocs\myText.txt";
```

In this way, the string literal isn't cluttered with escape characters and makes it much more readable.

What I would like to know is whether PHP also has an equivalent or do I have to manually escape the string myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$path = 'C:\MyDocs\myText.txt';
```

`"` double quotes allow for all sorts of special character sequences, `'` single quotes are verbatim (there's only some [fine print](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) about escaping `'` and escaping an escape `\`).

Answer (score 4):

Even single-quoted strings in PHP have the need for escaping at least literal single-quotes <strike>and literal backslashes</strike>:

```
$str = 'Single quotes won\'t help me \ avoid escapes or save a tree';
```

The only non-parsed solution for PHP is to use [nowdocs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).  This requires you use PHP 5.3.

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
I mustn't quote verbatim text \
maybe in the version next
EOD;
```

Comment: You don't need to escape backslashes, unless they could be escaping a single quote.